# ffmpeg - How to change the filter-paramaters depending on time oder framenumber?

Tags: dynamic, filter, ffmpeg, parameters, pixelate

Hallo to all userse and helpers here in this forum! Thank you, i am new and i have found allready a lot of solutions.

Now I want to ask, if someone can help me:

I have a Movie about 30 seconds made of 1 image.
Now I want to pixelate depending on  time or framenumber - every time a litlle bit less.
My code so far:

ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf scale=iw/n:ih/n,scale=n*iw:n*ih:flags=neighbor out.mp4

where n should be the framenumber 1 to 900.
this scould also be t+1 for slower change.

the stars are gone - so i mean n times iw:n times ih:

error-massage:

undefined constant or missing '(' in 'n'
error when evaluating the expression 'ih/n'
maybe the expression for out_w:'w/n' or for out_h:'ih/n' is self-referencing.
failed to configure output pad on paresed_scale_0
error reinitializing filters!
failed to inject frame into filter network: invalid argument
error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0

Do you have some suggestion plaese - Thank you in Advance

Comment: Animation parameters in scale.are only supported in recent git versions. See https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Options-1. Also, all frames will have to scaled to the same size for output.

Comment: Thank you Gyan - but this is not a question of scaling. This is about to increase or decrease or change filterparameters with the framenumber (n) oder playtime in seconds (t). Any other suggestion?

Comment: There's no generic mechanism across filters for using n and t - it is implemented in some filters. You're using two scale filters. For scale, it is only available in recent git.

Comment: thank you again! maybe there is a batch-possibility where i can load the parameter for n from a table- or text-file?